gtsummary superscripts/footnotes with kableextra
I'm trying to display gtsummary output using kableExtra. The issue is that the superscripts corresponding to footnotes disappear when I feed to as_kable_extra
Example:
---
title: "Kable Test"
output:
  pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=TRUE}

iris  |> 
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(
    by = 'Species'
  ) |> 
  gtsummary::as_kable_extra(
    booktabs = TRUE,
    format = 'latex'
  )

```

The HTML output in the viewer before adding as_kable_extra is correct with superscripts in the column headers:

But when rendered:

Suggestions?
Thank you

I believe you can modify the table with some regular expressions to get the superscript back in. From here you should be able to render the table.
library(gtsummary)
library(kableExtra)
library(stringr)

t1 <- iris  |> 
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(
    by = 'Species'
  ) |> 
  gtsummary::as_kable_extra(
    booktabs = TRUE,
    format = 'latex'
  ) 

t1 <- knitr::asis_output(str_replace_all(t1, "N = 50", "N = 50$^{1}$"))

