How to move footnote reference in gtsummary table
Consider the following example:
library(gtsummary)
trial |> 
  tbl_summary(include = c(age)) |>
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "\\makecell{{**{level}**, \\\\ N = {n}}}")

Which results in a table with the following header:

I would like to move the footnote reference superscript ¹ before the close curly bracket.
Equivalently, given:
library(gtsummary)
library(gt)
trial |> 
  tbl_summary(include = c(age)) |>
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "\\makecell{{**{level}**, \\\\ N = {n}}}") |>
  as_gt() |>
  as_latex() |>
  as.character() |>
  cat()

which results in:
\begin{table}[!t]
\fontsize{12.0pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lc}
\toprule
\textbf{Characteristic} & \textbackslash{}makecell\{\textbf{Overall}, \textbackslash{} N = 200\}\textsuperscript{\textit{1}} \\ 
\midrule\addlinespace[2.5pt]
Age & 47 (38, 57) \\ 
    Unknown & 11 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\textsuperscript{\textit{1}}Median (Q1, Q3)\\
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

I want to move \textsuperscript{\textit{1}} after N = 200.
How can I do it?

does this post help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79071757/gtsummary-superscripts-footnotes-with-kableextra/79115373#79115373

no it doesn't. It is substituting an exact match with another (N = 50 with N = 50 \textsuperscript{}). The whole point of this is to be resilient to changes in variables and reproducible.
